# Change PS1 color when connected to other host via SSH

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

I'm trying to change PS1 look based on what host I'm connected in using SSH. My current PS1:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[1;34m\] \w\[\e[1;31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[1;0;37m\] \$\[\e[0m\] '
```

For host `host1` I'd like to replace the first color with yellow which is `1;33` and for `host2` take `1;35` as an example.

How can I figure out that I'm connected to the given host using SSH and alter PS1 accordingly?

Comment: In the remote hosts's shell initialisation file: `if [[ -n $SSH_CLIENT ]]; then...`

Comment: That's sound like a good solution. What can I change part of the PS1 by extracting it to a variable? I've tried like COLOR='some color' and using it in PS1='$COLOR\u@\uh...' but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just use two PS1's: the first in the `if` condition with your SSH colours, the second is your normal prompt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Construct your prompt specification in pieces, or use intermediate variables, or a combination of both. SSH sets the `SSH_CLIENT` variable, which indicates where you're logged in from. You can then use the host name to determined where you're logged into.

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CLIENT ]]; then
  case $HOSTNAME in
    *.example.com) prompt_user_host_color='1;35';; # magenta on example.com
    *) prompt_user_host_color='1;33';; # yellow elsewhere
  esac
else
  unset prompt_user_host_color # omitted on the local machine
fi
if [[ -n $prompt_user_host_color ]]; then
  PS1='\[\e['$prompt_user_host_color'm\]\u@\h'
else
  PS1=
fi
PS1+='\[\e[1;34m\] \w\[\e[1;31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[1;0;37m\] \$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Comment: Please add `\[` ahead of  `\e`, otherwise it won't work. Thanks for the solution, it's perfect!

Comment: You may remove the `;;` trailing the `unset` command in the `else` block.

Comment: I understand this configuration needs  to be placed in the client `.bashrc` file. How can then it be used by the ssh client if there is a similar file on the server ?

Comment: @Stephane I don't understand your question. This file is not used by the client, and it is not meant to be used on the client.

Comment: @Gilles The `if case` statement in your example script sort of tells me it displays a different color depending on a domain name. I thought these domain names were ones of servers. And so your script is on the client side. I'm confused.

Comment: @Stephane The script sets the color based on the name of the machine that it's running on. It uses `SSH_CLIENT` to detect whether it's running in an SSH session. If it is (i.e. if it's running on the SSH server) then it sets the prompt color. If it isn't running on an SSH session, i.e. if you logged in on the console, then the prompt isn't colored.

Comment: @Gilles And so the domain names in the scripts are there only to make the script compatible if it is copied on multiple servers ?

Comment: @Stephane Yes, the analysis of `$HOSTNAME` wouldn't be useful if the code was only ever placed on a single server. People who log in to multiple machines often replicate their configuration files to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other one, but you *could* also use the separate rc file for `ssh`.

```sh
<<\SSH_RC \
    tee -a ~/.ssh/rc
case $HOSTNAME in
    (host1) sshclr=1;;
    (host2) sshclr=3;;
esac
```

...and wherever you are assigning your `$PS1`...

```
PS1="\[\e[1;$((32+ssh_clr))"'...
```

...you could leave it in single quotes, too...

```
PS1='\[\e[$((!$?|4));$((32+sshclr))...'
```

...which should underline if the last command executed exited with a non-zero exit code. Here's a picture...

[image]

I added the `${SSH_CLIENT+ssh:}` expansion there to clearly denote `@ssh:` when connected that way...