# Command Run Differently Depending on How Logged In?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there a way to have one command run differently, depending on the manner in which one is logged into the session launching it?

Basically, we have a command that when run, launches vim to display a file.  I would like it to run using vim if I'm connected via ssh, and macvim if I am on the console.

I can write the script, but I can't find how to get the console or the ptty.  `w` lists all sessions.

Thanks.

Comment: PS Yes, this is a business-related question.  We use Macs for development of ecommerce.

Comment: There are lots of ways to tell the difference. Which one is appropriate depends on why you want it to behave differently in the first place. For example if you want to run two different commands depending on whether X11 is available or not, you would need to test if you have a functional DISPLAY environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you connect via SSH, the `SSH_CLIENT` environmental variable will be set, along with `SSH_CONNECTION` and `SSH_TTY`. You can use these to check if the user is logged on remotely.

Comment: The [ssh(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh.1.html) man page mentions indeed `SSH_CONNECTION` and `SSH_TTY`, but I haven't noticed `SSH_CLIENT`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217270/change-ps1-color-when-connected-to-other-host-via-ssh