# How to use regex negative lookahead?

Tags: regular-expression, iterm2

I'm trying to use iTerm2 profile triggers on my mac to change the prompt if I leave my home directory.  This rule should only apply when the node I'm on has a hostname of `headnode`.  The prompt will also include the machine's location in parenthesis after the hostname.  I'm trying to build a regex that will match any directory unless it includes `~`.

So it should match:

```
[jbutryn@headnode (us-west-a) /]$
```

but not:

```
[jbutryn@headnode (us-west-a) ~]$
or
[jbutryn@headnode (us-west-a) ~/tmp]$
etc.
```

Currently I'm building my regex like this:

```
\[.*\@headnode.*(?!\~).*].
```

But that matches all examples above.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Unless you bring your prompt with you to any other host which you might log into, hostname detection won't work, as when you log into a new host, you get a new environment including a freshly-set `PS1`.

Comment: This is a feature of iterm2, it can literally just match regex patterns and take action based off them on your local machine.  Maybe I'm using the word prompt incorrectly but essentially I just want iTerm to highlight it red when I'm not in the home directory.  The highlight function definitely works I just can't get the match to work correctly.

Comment: The iterm trigger feature:  https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html

Comment: You can also do this within the shell. [Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217270/change-ps1-color-when-connected-to-other-host-via-ssh/217275#217275).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\[.*\@headnode.*(?!\~).*\]
```

Matches on

1. `[` followed by
2. `.*`: a sequence of 0 or more characters followed by
3. `@headnode` followed by
4. `.*`: a sequence of 0 or more characters that is not followed by
5. `~`, followed by
6. `.*`: a sequence of 0 or more characters followed by:
7. `]`

It does match on:

```
[jbutryn@headnode (us-west-a) ~/tmp]$
```

Because that's:

```
<[><jbutryn><@headnode>< (us-west-a) ~/tmp><><]>$
 1  2        3          4                  6  7
```

What follows `4` is not `~`.

You'd need the negative look ahead to be at a position that matches something specific in the text, like after the first word after `@headnode`:

```
\[.*\@headnode \S+ (?!\~).*\]
```

Comment: I don't understand the function of the `\S+` here... is it `whitespace`?

Answer (score 0):

Working off [Stéphane's breakdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385003/80216#385007), I suggest a slightly different solution. 
Since the signal to stop including stuff in his item 4 is only a single character wide, it's easy to construct a class that includes all characters EXCEPT the signal characters – or, in this case, single character.

In other words, replace the portion of the regular expression in his #4 with just this:

```
[^~]*
```

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging that your answer is building on somebody else’s answer.  However, your answer would be better if you gave a complete, standalone solution. (For example, consider how useless your answer would become if Stéphane’s answer disappeared.) In particular, I believe that you would need to replace parts 4 through 6.